# How to use "acceptable" in response to a question

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

Suppose someone asks how I'm doing. Which form of the word "acceptable" is grammatically correct to use for a response? Is it "Acceptable", "Acceptably", "I'm acceptable", "I'm acceptably", "I'm doing acceptable", "I'm doing acceptably", or something else?

(I do understand that it's probably unnatural or even impolite way to answer this question.)

Comment: Replying with *acceptable*, in any form, seems unidiomatic to me. I've never heard anybody reply with that word. And, barring it being meant as something humorous, can't really imagine it being used normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Acceptably" or "I'm doing acceptably" would be correct.

Personally, I usually go for answering with an adjective (e.g. "good" or "acceptable") rather than an adverb (e.g. "well" or "acceptably") even thought it's not correct, since it's what most people expect and you don't want to sound too uptight. That might be an American thing though.